# Is it possible to create a database driven website with flash?

Tags: database, flash, web-applications, web

I am a newbie programmer and i dont yet have any idea of the WEB. I wish to start learning a technology that will allow me to build websites( database driven) i dont know which one to choose. I know some actionscript3 and flash.

Is it possible to create a database driven website using these alone? Or do i need to learn any other technology? If i do then what should i learn? I know j2se for the desktop and oracle SQL/MySQL

please show me a path. Also wanted to know if there is any technology like Wordpress for J2EE/flash

OK so i finally got the feeling that i need to learn PHP anyway along with css and javascript. So it is fine. Also another query. Which CMS should i consider? Wordpress or Joomla?

Comment: Don't build websites with flash alone. That is a niche. Learn web techniques. HTML/CSS/JS/Servers/SQL/Backend of choice

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing their perspectives. I think i will go by learning html+php+css for now as these are the most reachable and resourceful around me.

Comment: don't forget javascript. It's simply neccessary these days because people don't put up with the postback model anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly = this question is too broad and generic, and answers are easily found with some google searches.

That being said = of course you can build a data driven flash site. The one caveat here is that flash itself is fundamentally client-side technology, so we must rely on other remote tech to do the heavy data lifting. The options are profuse.

For example, a developer might create a front facing presentation in Flex, which is the streamlined, data-centric extension of pure flash. His database interactions are written in php, and these are constantly called upon to deliver content to the user.

So - what technologies to use? *Whatever you know*. And if you don't know, then learn the ones that are closest to what you know.

Finally, although I am a die-hard fan of flash, this type of project (you didn't specify what you had in mind) could be done with many different technologies. So - maybe flash is the right answer, but maybe javascript (ajax) could manage the same thing and do it without the need of plugins.

Comment: I am willing to develop interactive flash websites this will involve a  dynamic section fetched from DB(like the one you see here in SOF) and some animation and games too.  I just wondered if flash is enough to set up a full website such as that.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is, at least on the front end, and there are certainly robust communication frameworks to streamline the process. I do think @Raynos's comment should be heeded. Especially with the evolution of js frameworks, the outright need for flash is certainly diminished.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop a database driven website using Flash, but only in the same sense that you can develop a database driven website using AJAX. That is, you can build the front-end using Flash/ActionScript but the back-end is built using other technologies. Just like working with JavaScript to develop a front-end, from ActionScript you would be communicating with Java or PHP or Python or something on the server using RESTful calls and then actually working with the database in the server-side scripts.

Comment: So.. i need to know how to build a database driven website with PHP/Java and i also need to know how to connect to Java/PHP with flash? What do you suggest me? Java with flash or PHP with flash?

Comment: For how to connect I would suggest standard techniques like making REST queries, but other options include Flash Remoting technology. As for which language to use, there's little technical difference so that mostly comes down to which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can develop database driven site in flash/action script but you still need and back-end technology i recommend you to check [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/) you can develop the back-end using Java, PHP, or .NET In addition you can use Flash Remoting technology Flash/Flex to communicate with a back-end

Comment: I have actually created a website that deals directly with a webservice via SOAP and actionscript. There was no PHP, Java, or anything else on the back-end except the webservice database. You can read Adobe's article here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html

Comment: However, it was difficult to get functioning properly since I had to work closely with the database developer so he could create some webservice functions that I could call and get results from. So, while it can be done, it is not the easiest way to do it. I have also done AS3 with a PHP back-end script library and mySQL database, and this was MUCH easier to implement!

Answer (score 0):

Flash can't be directly connected to database. You must use another technique which would be "mediator". I have developed Flash game with MySql database and PHP and I recommend you to use this combination. Here is visually presented this kind of communication: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRi-oxjFfCU

Answer (score -1):

yes, it is possible to crate database driven website with flash and action-script. 
 You would get an XML file when you do action script in flash, so you can store nodes of that XML file into database(mysql). You can then create an Admin interface to manage your database contents, that would indirectly change your xml nodes. So basically you can edit the xml file and store it in the database.

Comment: -1 due to the fact that storing stuff as XML and reading it from ActionScript is slow as hell, not to mention bad practice.

Therefore I deem it to be unhelpful because it is not a good answer to his question.